# Using common order by for both query with union function

Tags: mysql, sql

Friends i'm using two queries with same concept in the below query i've used two order by function instead i would like to write only one order by function for the whole query using same attribute date_time DESC is it possible in mysql

```
(SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_from` = '18' AND `chat_to` = '13' ORDER BY `date_time` DESC ) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_from` = '13' AND `chat_to` = '18' ORDER BY `date_time` DESC )
```

Comment: yes it is, try this in mysql console and see whether it is giving expected output or not

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM `chats` 
WHERE `chat_from` IN(18,13) 
AND `chat_to`IN(18,13) 
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC
```

Comment: ...or maybe even simpler for MySQL `SELECT * FROM chats  WHERE (chat_from, chat_to) IN((18,13),(13,18)) ORDER BY date_time DESC;`

Comment: And you also need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, to remove duplicates (just like `UNION` does.)

Comment: @jarlh The original query in the question doesn't find 13,13 or 18,18. You're naturally correct about the `DISTINCT`, however I wonder if there are really any completely identical rows from selecting `*` on the table or the OP just didn't know the distinction from `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(
 SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_from`in ('18','13') and `chat_to` in ('18','13')  
)
t1 ORDER BY `date_time` DESC
```

Comment: You need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, to remove duplicates (just like `UNION` does.)

Comment: @jarlh if he need different value then he may use distinct ...select distinct * from 'chats'..

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `chats` 
WHERE 
    (
        `chat_from` = '18' 
        AND `chat_to` = '13'
    ) 
    OR
    (
        `chat_from` = '13' 
        AND `chat_to` = '18' 
    ) 
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC
```

If you need them to be distinct then you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `chats`...
```